# How do I write a regex to match the module instantiation in a Verilog file?

Tags: regex, perl, verilog

I am working on a project to facilitate verilog programming by using perl scripting language. Now I want to write a script to scan a top verilog file, and then generate the hierarchy list for the module, which suggests that I need to extract the module instantiation
statement from the verilog file, here is the problem:

How to write a regular expression to match the module instantiation in a verilog file, since we need to know the submodule names of the top module file.

Comment: Have you [searched?](http://search.cpan.org/search?q=verilog;s=1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `SYNOPSIS` of [Verilog::Netlist](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Verilog::Netlist) shows how to read in a Verilog file and find modules throughout the hierarchy.  Although you could use regular expressions in some limited cases, it would be worthwhile to use this CPAN parser module in the long run.

Here is some example code I posted on PerlMonks a while back: [verilog perl usage (Verilog::Netlist)](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node=750691)

The [vhier](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?vhier) script which is part of the [Verilog-Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Verilog-Perl/) distribution is also handy.

Comment: Really thanks, I do use the CPAN to find some approprate module for use, but I could not successfully install them (some thing like Verilog::Language) under window environment by using the ActiveState Perl. Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the link of nice demonstrations of verilog-perl on perlmonks to start off.