# Verilog gate level parser

Tags: parsing, bison, verilog, lex, cad

I want to parse Verilog gate level code and store the data in a data structure (ex. graph).

Then I want to do something on the gates in C/C++ and output a corresponding Verilog file.

(I would like to build one program which input and output are Verilog gate level code)

(`input.v => myProgram => output.v`)

If there is any library or open source code to do so?

I found that it can be done by Flex and Bison but I have no idea how to use Flex and Bison.

Answer (score 1):

There was [a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16524749/97073) a few days ago about  doing this in ruby, in which I pointed to my [Verilog](https://rubygems.org/gems/verilog) parser gem. Not sure if it is robust enough for you though, would love feedback, bug reports, feature requests.

There are perl verilog parsers out there but I have not used any of them directly and avoid perl, hopefully others can add info about other parsers.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [Verilog-Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Verilog-Perl/) successfully to parse Verilog code.  It is well-maintained: it even supports the recent SystemVerilog extensions.

See also: [How do I write a regex to match the module instantiation in a Verilog file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066483/how-do-i-write-a-regex-to-match-the-module-instantiation-in-a-verilog-file)

Answer (score 1):

Yosys (https://github.com/cliffordwolf/yosys) is a framework for Verilog Synthesis written in C++. Yosys is still under construction but if you only want to read and write gate-level netlists it can do what you need..

PS: A reference manual (that also covers the C++ APIs) is on the way. I've written ~100 pages already, but can't publish it before I've finished my BSc. thesis (another month or so).